# OpenGL ES crash on move background, iOS 5.1

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es

I have a little issue about my application iOS.
When i'm using the iOS simulator 5.1 ipad/iphone the application is working, but when i use a real iOS device (iPad and iPhone 5.1 too)

the application crashes when moving on background after clicking on home button...
with this error:

```
libGPUSupportMercury.dylib`gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient:
0x33240094:  trap   
0x33240096:  nop
```

I found out that it's was OpenGL ES that was still calculating and making the application crash and found this function: glFinish();

But that still not working here a sample of my code:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    glFinish();
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
}
```

I think the problem is just here
Is there someone who have an idea of my problem ?
Thanks

EDIT:

Problem solved with that:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];
}
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] startAnimation];
}
```

maybe that can help someone x)

Comment: If you don't need to save any settings upon exit, this will work too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878604/how-do-i-shut-down-opengl-tasks-in-applicationwillresignactive

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In iOS 5.1 it is enforced that you cannot make a call to OpenGL after you have been requested to resign active.

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Is the place to stop everything, whether it be a CADisplayLink or a [[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation]

Comment: yes thanks, i edited when i found that i forgot to stop the animation x)

Comment: The docs referenced by @sup (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/ImplementingaMultitasking-awareOpenGLESApplication/ImplementingaMultitasking-awareOpenGLESApplication.html) say that OpenGL calls can (and in some cases should) be made from applicationDidEnterBackground - which executes after applicationWillResignActive. Please link to docs that disagree with sup's docs, otherwise please update.

Comment: Note that if you call OpenGL ES asyn from background it will still crash from time to time because the block continues calling opengl even after you told the display link or timer to stop. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215554/how-to-stop-opengl-drawing-when-calling-opengl-from-background

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the last method you can make OpenGL calls from is this one:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

Although it is often a good idea to suspend drawing after applicationWillResignActive, this is just a recommendation and some apps have requirements beyond this. What is actually *enforced* is that you cannot make any OpenGL calls once your app moves to the background.

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/ImplementingaMultitasking-awareOpenGLESApplication/ImplementingaMultitasking-awareOpenGLESApplication.html):

> Once your application exits its applicationDidEnterBackground: method,
>   it must not make any new OpenGL ES calls. If your application makes an
>   OpenGL ES call, it is terminated by iOS.

Also, remember to include glFinish() as your final GL call.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the FPS node on the screen, it might be rendering..

*edit - and check for audio playing