# How do I shut down OpenGL tasks in applicationWillResignActive?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, crash

I have nearly completed my first app. In testing on the device, I am getting a crash when I press the home button, with the error message

libGPUSupportMercury.dylib`gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient:

Based on these posts:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+shut+down+OpenGL
[OpenGL ES crash on move background, iOS 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620287/opengl-es-crash-on-move-background-ios-5-1)

I am pretty sure the problem is that my app is an extension of software that uses some sample code involving OpenGL (about which I have very little understanding) and that the OpenGL tasks are not shutting down properly on resignActive.

I tried the following in my AppDelegate with no luck:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    glFinish();
}
```

My app does not need to save any settings upon exit... it just needs to end.
Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To finish program at user push home button ?
on Xcode, choice Target and select Info tab.
Custom iOS Target Properties, add a Key named

Application does not run in background

and set Value

YES

Try it!

p.s. Not necessary write glFinish().

Comment: That did it! Amazing... I thought it was going to be much more complicated! Thank you, @koki.

Comment: @Jeanne - I really don't think terminating your application entirely upon going to the background is the correct solution here. You're treating the symptoms, not the disease. This is a terrible user experience, because the application now has to restart every time the user goes back to it. Instead, find out why your application is trying to keep rendering to OpenGL ES while it is in the background, and pause the render loop that triggers this.

Comment: @Brad Larson, thank you... I definitely agree that it would be better to root out the problem (although it really does not affect the user experience, as the interface is so simple that there are no settings to be saved). Unfortunately, I have not yet learned anything at all about OpenGL- I simply built an original interface around a levelMeter (from SpeakHere sample project). I'm happy to do more research- if you know of any good and really basic tutorials on OpenGL,, I will check them out.

Comment: @Jeanne - You don't even need to know OpenGL ES to fix this. Simply find what is triggering your rendering to update and make sure that isn't allowed to fire when your application has gone to the background. You might be able to use a simple boolean value for this that is set when you go to the background and is checked when your rendering method is called. If it's false, the rendering never runs and you avoid this crash without needing to completely shut down your application. I do a similar pausing of rendering in one of my applications, and it's very simple to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I am now working on a Sprite Kit game and I had a similar problem.

Check if you have on the screen the node that tells the FPS, because that might be rendering and causing the crash.. It did for me.

In applicationWillResignActive method I call my pause method as all of you.

*edit - and check for audio playing