# root.plist dymamic change of display information

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsuserdefaults, root.plist

How can one possibly display an information paragraph within settings.app? I'd use root.plist and NSUserDefaults group footer. But how can I link these two together, so the information can be modified dynamically from the app?

I would like to display information like: @"Your secret user code is: %d", userCode. And change the userCode every time the user e.g. purchases something.

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620287/opengl-es-crash-on-move-background-ios-5-1

Comment: @birukaze That's about something completely different

Comment: @KutakMir: are you able to change the title dynamically.